# Some components inside KeyboardAvoidingView jump

Tags: react-native, keyboard

I realized some components inside `KeyboardAvoidingView` moves without animation while others transition smoothly as the keyboard appears or disappears.

[The example code on the official React Native doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview#example) is a good example. In this code, the `TextInput` component moves up smoothly while the header text jumps when the keyboard appears or disappears.

What causes some components to jump while others to move smoothly? How I can make all components inside `KeyboardAvoidingView` transition smoothly?

PS: This seems to happen when `justifyContent: "space-around"` is set in any of the descendent components.